# In Android, got click-jacked into clicking "Allow" for a pop-up that flashed for 0.1 seconds. How do I find out what I allowed?

Tags: security, browser

In Android, I was using Google Chrome. I clicked on a sketchy website which popped up a new chrome tab. I pressed the tabs button which caused me to view the various tabs. Right as I was clicking on an "X" of the top-most tab, a pop-up appeared with the "Allow" button exactly under my index finger so I accidentally pressed "Allow". I had no idea what the pop-up said, except that there were two blue word buttons, and I clicked the right-most one. What did I accidentally allow and how do I disable it?

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without knowing what "sketchy website" this was (and even then, as they might have changed that). Best guess would be something like accessing location or microphone – or, contempory (GDPR), to flood you with cookies and trackers.

Comment: Check your mobile balance first. You may have been tricked into WAP billing.